# How to understand the vector math behind glm::distance and glm::length?

Tags: c++, math, vector, glm-math

I found the following page: https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00131.html

And I am having issues with understanding why the following two are equivalent...

The following code:

```
 glm::vec3 vec = vector1 - vector2;  
 distance = glm::length(vec);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
 distance = glm::distance(vector1, vector2);
```

How is it that the length of the vector resulting in subtracting two vectors is equivalent to the distance between the vectors?

Comment: This seems like a mathematical misunderstanding, how would you define the distance between two vectors?

Comment: That's exactly how the distance between two points A and B is defined. In  mathematical terms ||(A - B)||. And that's exactly what the first code does.

Comment: They are using the same type for vectors and coordinates. The naming is simply bad. It should be something like `vec = point1 - point2`.

Comment: You should read up on vector math and linear algebra. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) is a good starting point.

Comment: It’s common among programmers to confuse things by identifying a point p with the vector from the origin to p. This reduces code duplication and increases bugs, and programmers traditionally prefer bugs over a slight inconvenience.

Comment: @local-ninja A point and a vector are the same thing. A position vector is just the representation of the coordinates of a point in a given reference frame. Since in code points will always be expressed as a coordinate they are equivalent.

Comment: @molbdnilo How would that increase bugs? The position vector is the representation of the point in a given coordinate frame, they are basically the same thing.

Comment: @Makogan Two different concepts such as points and vectors should not share the same type, just because they have the same representation in memory. With the right naming, there would be no confusion of what the difference between `length(vector)` and `distance(point, point)` is.

Comment: @local-ninja They are NOT different concepts. A vector is a point is a vector. Ask any mathematician. And the confusion is only present due to lack of experience with the math (which is understandable). Any person with enough familiarity with linear algebra understands what the length of a vector is and what the distance between vectors is.

There's no meaningful difference between a point and a vector, the proof is, add a point to a vector and you get a point (e.g. point  + normal), this tells you they are algebraically compatible, which means they are the same kind of object.

Answer (score 4):

This diagram might help understand what is happening here:
we have two vectors, **a** and **b**, which correspond to your vector1 and vector2. The difference vector of those two reaches from **b** to **a**. Its length equals exactly the distance between the two coordinates that describe **a** and **b**. If you switch **a** and **b** around, the difference vector simply changes direction.

[image]

Comment: thank you for pointing out this mistake, I was a bit too quick. I fixed it in the diagram.

Comment: A "better" pronunciation for "-" than "minus" (which doesn’t actually *mean* anything) is "from". "a - b" tells you how to get "to a from b". In this case, we then take the length of that path. This pronunciation is helpful in general, not just for vectors.